# Keep checked value of Yii radiobuttonlist after submit

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

I'm using a radioButtonList like this one:

```
$form->radioButtonList(Store::model(), 'product',
                       array(CODE1 => TEXT1,
                             CODE2 => TEXT2,
                             CODE3 => TEXT3)
                       );
```

This radioButtonList is part of a form with more fields. After submiting, if any field is incorrect, I show some error message and populate the correct fields using $_POST.

All the fields get its previous values except this radioButtonList. I need to set checked the value of the radioButtonList which was selected before submit, but I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Create `$model = new Store();` in your action, pass it to view and use `$model` variable instead `Store::model()`. This should help.

UPD: You need to use the same `$model` after validation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before but didn't work out for me. Isn't there any way to just set the value of the radioButtonList directly?

Comment: Sure, HtmlOptions param should help.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#radioButtonList-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
CHtml::radioButtonList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ));

In Your case it will be

CHtml::radioButtonList('product',$_POST[product],array(CODE1 => TEXT1,CODE2 => TEXT2,CODE3 => TEXT3));

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution. (not an elegant one, but it works)

From the view:

```
Store::model()->product = $_POST["Store"]["product"];
```

Right before display the radioButtonList